# Split and Assign char

Tags: c++, char, arduino

I am new to C++ and Arduino.

I have 3 variable of type char

```
char receivePayload[31];
char devID;
char switchState;
```

the data in receivePayload woudl be some like "01:01" or "01:00". Here the first part before colon is device ID and second part is switchState.

Can you please help me and explain how I can split the 2. I did read about strtok but was unable to understand.

The desired output would be like

```
devID would have 01 stored and 
switchState would have 01 or 00 stored.
```

Also if I can convert it into integer.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Correction: You have *two* variables of type `char`, and one variable of type array of `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is Arduino, you should probably use the [`String`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) class since it handles a lot of the annoying stuff for you like conversion to `int` without having to explicitly link against `glibc`.

You could split the string like so:

```
String receivedPayload("01:10");
String devId = receivedPayload.substring(0, receivedPayload.indexOf(':'));
String switchState = receivedPayload.substring(receivedPayload.indexOf(':'));
```

Converting them into an integer would involve just using [`toInt`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToInt) on the string objects.

If you didn't need to convert into an integer, it would have been easier to tokenise the string yourself by using a for loop and checking if the character is equal to `':'` since the string is so short.

Comment: I added reference to string.h, The string functions are available, how can I assign char into string.
I did the below:
String rcvPayld = receivePayload;
I get error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'
Any suggestions please.

Comment: I also tried String rcvPayld(receivePayload); and got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

As for your problem, there are multiple solutions to it: One is using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) as tokenizer. Another is using [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). Yet another solution is to use the old C function [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok).

The above solutions all give you *strings*, so either you have to make `devId` and `switchState` strings as well, or use e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert the strings to integers.

---

Apparently the Arduino platform have neither of the functionality listed above, which mean you have to tokenize the string yourself. This is, however, very simple: Find the separator (the `':'` character), copy from the beginning to (but not including) the separator into a temporary string and convert it to an integer with e.g. [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol). Then copy from (but not including) the separator into the temporary string and convert that value to an integer.

If you don't even have `std::strtol` then use [`std::atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi).

Comment: Arduino has neither of these.

Comment: @Rapptz Not even `strtok`?

Comment: Not that I know of. It doesn't have many functions from glibc (not even `printf`).

Comment: But You can link against them. Just include them (you have to import them)